# How i can add proxy extension into this code?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code for my instagram automation tool.I want to add proxy before my bot start.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

mobile_emulation = {
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"}

options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

bot = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=CM().install())
bot.set_window_size(500, 950)

bot.get('https://instagram.com')
```

Comment: Which proxy do you want to use?

Comment: Private proxy.I have ip,port number,id and password.